# How to set expected response from server only status and cookie

Tags: typescript, rest, next.js, cookies, redux-toolkit

I use Redux Toolkit Query to refresh occasionally jwt token:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const refreshApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}`,
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    refreshAuthorization: builder.query({
      query: () => "/api/auth/refresh",
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useRefreshAuthorizationQuery } = refreshApi;
```

this what my server will response with:

```
    return res
        .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
           httpOnly: true,
           secure: config.get("isSecure"),
           sameSite: "none",
      })
```

But I got this error:
[image]

seems like front expect json but I only return status

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, by default Redux-Toolkit Query `fetchBaseQuery` function assumes JSON responses. If I am not mistaken, the cookie response content type is `"text/html"`. You can override specific endpoints' response handler to specify this.

Example:

```js
export const refreshApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}`,
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    refreshAuthorization: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/api/auth/refresh",
        responseHandler: "text",
        // or
        // responseHandler: response => response.text();
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

For more details see [Individual Query Options](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#individual-query-options), specifically [Parsing a Response](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response).